# Can I delete files and folders in /private/var/tmp folder?

Tags: macos, mojave, sip, google-apps, anti-virus

I ran into the situation where using simultaneously Google Drive File Stream (DFS) and Code42 Crashplan and some other Corporate SW like CrowdStrike's Falcon, Bitdefender, etc... which seems are not liking each other (see [this article](https://support.google.com/a/thread/6145699?hl=en)).

Anyway, there turned up two issues:

1. one which was manageable in user accessible space (DFS cache was ~60GB)
2. the other beyond standard user access, where in `/private/var/tmp` folder occupied 210+GB

Resolving issue #1 was relatively "trivial" still not sure how to go around it in the future.
Resolving issue #2 took me several days of investigation and trials.

Comment: What do you mean by "beyond standard user access"? Which specific files are we talking about here, what are their permissions, what happens if you run `sudo rm -r` on them? Please also add the result of `ls -leO /prvate/var/tmp` as text.

Comment: If https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252140451?answerId=254063186022#254063186022 shows your output, I don't see why `sudo rm -r` shouldn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The solution now, seems quite straight forward possible to achieve in 5 or 6 main steps.

Not to repeat myself here again, I'd rather post link to Apple forum where I post similar question: [How to safely delete a content of /private/var/tmp](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252140451?answerId=254071297022#254071297022)

Comment: Answers should be more than just off-site links. Please add your steps directly into your answer here so people can see it, find it via site search etc.

Comment: Also properly posting here prevents « link rot ».